# Value is set by getter/setter cant be updated after input reset

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a form that when I use the below snippet in the controller

```javascript
const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
    if ( inputFields ) {
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
            field.reset();
        } );
    }
```

I am then unable to update a value that was previously set via a getter/setter. Full code below for reference

HTML

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card  title="Log Records">
        <form>
            <div if:true={isLoaded} class="slds-is-relative">
                <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand">
                </lightning-spinner>
            </div>
            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small">
                    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Quality_Assurance_Checks__c">
                        <lightning-input-field  field-name = "Case_Task__c" required="true" value={caseTask} name="caseTask" onchange={handleFieldChange}></lightning-input-field>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name = "Due_Date__c"  class="childField" value={dueDate} onchange={handleFieldChange} name="dueDate"></lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
                </lightning-layout-item> 
            </lightning-layout>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" title="Primary action" onclick={reset} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>

</template>
```

Controller

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import Id from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue, getRecordNotifyChange  } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import BUILD_REC from '@salesforce/schema/Case_Task__c.Build_For__c';
import createQACheck from '@salesforce/apex/qualityAssuranceCheckController.createQACheck';

const fields = [BUILD_REC];
export default class QualityAssuranceCheckComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    userId = Id;
    errorMessage; 
    isLoaded = false; 

    @api recordId; 
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    lead; 

    get caseTask() {
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, BUILD_REC);
    }

    set caseTask(value){
        this.newCaseTask = value; 
    }
    
    get defCaseTask(){
        return getFieldValue(this.lead.data, BUILD_REC);
    }

    handleFieldChange(event){
        console.log(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.name);
        
        if(event.target.name === 'dueDate'){
            this.dueDate = event.target.value; 
        }
        if(event.target.name === 'caseTask'){
            this.newCaseTask = event.target.value; 
        }

        console.log(this.caseTask);
    }

    reset(){
        const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field');
        if ( inputFields ) {
            inputFields.forEach( field => {
                field.reset();
            } );
        }
    this.newCaseTask = this.defCaseTask; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring `newCaseTask` and `dueDate` on the class.

You need to define them:

```
export default class QualityAssuranceCheckComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
  dueDate;
  newCaseTask = "";
  //....ect
```

If you don't declare these as class members, calls to `this.dueDate` and `this.newCaseTask` will cause an error because they don't exist.

I also noticed this:

```
this.newCaseTask = this.defCaseTask;
```

This is not in a function and will be executed as part of the class load. At this point `this.defCaseTask` will be null. Again, you can't use `this` at the class level.

You need to define a wireHandler method and assign `newCaseTask` there.

Something like:

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })  
wiredLeadHandler({ error, data }) {
  if (data) {
    this.lead = data;
    //this will work because you will have defined newCaseTask
    //and you are doing this in a method
    this.newCaseTask = this.defCaseTask;
  } 
  else if (error) {
    this.error = error;
  }
}
```

Comment: No dice. For reference, I do not have this issue with the userId variable (which is not used in a getter/setter). I can make updates to it without problem.

Comment: That's because you have declared userId as a member of the class. I see you have also not declared dueDate. Which is why it's still not working. You will be getting an error (visible in the console) when you try to set these values. I've edited my answer to add dueDate. userId was there just to give context.